# nonce search algorithm

Tags: mining-theory, nonce

I have a question about the nonce search algorithm.
Let's say I have a s9 miner and my competitor has a more powerful s19. We both check nonces from 0 sequentially, so I will check nonces that my competitor has already checked.
Does it make sense to use a random nonce to increase mining efficiency?

Comment: Hi Oleh, I think your question is answered on one of these related topics already: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36192/5406 or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1236/5406. This is not an issue because every miner works on unique block templates.—If you agree with my assessment, please flag your questions as a duplicate of the one that you feel fits best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How cooperative or competitive is the mining process?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/how-cooperative-or-competitive-is-the-mining-process)