# Why did GBT fail?

Tags: mining-pools, getblocktemplate

GBT was a way to stop miner centralization, but no one used it, everyone continued to use Stratum. Why did it fail?

Comment: Closely related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55015/does-stratum-cause-mining-to-be-more-centralized-than-getblocktemplate-would

Comment: Why do you assume it failed? It is in nearly every - if not all - miner setups. Just not for communication with the hashing hardware